# Jetty 8.1.2 startup delay

Tags: jetty

Similar to the question  [Jetty startup delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398268/jetty-startup-delay) the startup time for a Jetty 8.1.2 raises with increasing amount of dependencies in the WEB-INF/lib directory. (20mb ~60 to 90 seconds)

With DEBUG enabled (-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG, see also this Answer [Enable Jetty DEBUG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398488/1180279)) the following line occurs massively in output:

```
2012-04-27 11:13:38.095:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [/home/.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpX/webapps]: {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a normal process since Servlet-API 2.5 which is looking for Servlet related Annotations in all Classes and Jars. Normally this could be avoided with the "metadata-complete" option in the web.xml:

```
<web-app metadata-complete="true" ...>
```

In Jetty 8.1.2 this is recognized due startup by the AnntionConfiguration Class but the scanning process occurs anyway. This is an known ISSUE [Jetty 8.1.2 scans all classes on classpath if there is >= 1xServletContainerInitializer with HandlesTypes on the classpath, regardless of metadata-complete="true"](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1503) for Jetty 8.1.2.

A workaround is to use a pattern to limit the JAR files which will be included in the scanning process. E.g. in Eclipse you can append the following snippet to the "jetty-context.xml" in "/home/.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpX/contexts/appname.xml" file:

```
<Call name="setAttribute">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
    <Arg>.*/.*myPrefixedJarToScan1-[^/]\.jar$|.*/.*myPrefixedJarToScan2-[^/]\.jar$</Arg>
</Call>
```