# Jetty startup delay due to scanning

Tags: spring, spring-security, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-9

**Context and setup information:**

- Jetty 9 with the eclipse jetty plugin
- Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE with Spring Security 3.2.3
- Spring Java Configuration (no web.xml)

**Problem description**
Starting jetty 9 is very slow in a project where Spring's JavaConfig is used to boot the Spring context instead of using a `web.xml`. Jetty seems to be doing nothing during a considerate amount of time. This occurs after the line:

`INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.3.v20140905`

Jetty does start eventually, but takes very long to start up compared to a regular tomcat 7 distribution.

---

**Additional resources**

```
    public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {    
    //implementation
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Jetty 9 scans all Jars in the WEB-INF folder for annotations  in order to start the web context. If you've attempted to find a solution to this problem, you probably already discovered that fact. I tried several such answers, but never found the correct solution among them.

In order to eliminate such scanning as much as possible, we can define a pattern that tells Jetty which sources to scan and which not to scan. This is done by either setting some configuration in maven, or by  setting an attribute in the `jetty-context.xml`. (If you are using the maven plugin, you need to set Jetty's `jetty-context.xml` also in your `pom.xml`)

Some other solutions that have not worked for me (either no increase in startup time or no correct startup at all)

[Jetty 8.1.2 startup delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348338/jetty-8-1-2-startup-delay)
[jetty8 with maven plugin takes to long to start](https://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/issues/detail?id=140)

etc.

The correct solution is also done using such `jetty-context.xml`, but with another pattern. In a Spring application, we need to scan the Spring jars, and this alone will already give a massive boost if you have many dependencies. Even better is if you only scan the `spring-web` jars instead. If you have Spring Security, then it might also be needed to include those jars.

As such, the pattern that gave me maximum speedup is shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <Call name="setAttribute">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
        <Arg>.*/spring-security[^/]*\.jar$|.*/spring-web[^/]*\.jar$|.*/classes/.*</Arg>
    </Call>

</Configure>
```

We exclude anything that is not in our `classes` folder in `WEB-INF`, as well as any jars that do not include the regex pattern given.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: There's also the `quickstart` module in Jetty 9.2.x that can do the scan at build/compile time, which creates a `jetty-quickstart.xml` of what it finds in the war file, making the production startup sub-second.

Comment: That's pretty cool actually. I'll try to find an example of how to do that, so I can add it to this answer, or you can submit your own if you have one in an answer :). Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any big difference regardless which solution I tried.

Comment: Are you sure the jetty-context is being used? If so, try tweaking the regular expression, there might be other big libraries that cause the delay.

Comment: If using Gradle instead of Maven, I could successfully apply this configuration using the Gretty plugin and setting the jetty-env configuration parameter .