# How to analyze startup performance when using jetty-maven-plugin:run

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm developing a java web application using java. To develop this application I'm using jetty as application server. Up to now the following version:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>7.4.2.v20110526</version>
</plugin>
```

After some changes in the application, I decide to change my jetty version with the following:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>9.2.13.v20150730</version>
</plugin>
```

But i noticed a performance lack during the execution of jetty:run.

[image]

I noticed that it loses almost a minute on

> 2015-10-07 12:59:11.863:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.13.v20150730

How can I understand why?

**Update 1**

I think that my problem could be similar at the following:

[Jetty startup delay due to scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927939/jetty-startup-delay-due-to-scanning)

then I thought to solve my problem using quick-start module, is this possible using jetty-embedded?

Comment: Some code/behavior of Jetty may have changed in the past 4 years. Maybe there is some option to configure it to print more logs: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

Comment: He's got slf4j present in his environment, he'll need to configure both the jetty specifics **and** the slf4j environment to get useful logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is indeed most probably caused by scanning. The link you've found has helpful info on it.

I have also just updated the documentation for the jetty-maven-plugin to make it clear that you can also set the patterns for container and webapp  jar scanning with the plugin. The page is here: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp  but it will take the CI system a little while to push out the update (look for items on setting the containerIncludeJarPattern and the webInfIncludeJarPattern).

As the document already mentions under the goal "effectiveWebXml", using quickstart explicitly with the maven plugins is not really appropriate.

Jan